# Pivot Tables and eloquent Laravel 5.5

Tags: laravel, eloquent

this is maybe the hardest problem I'm facing since I use laravel and I hope some of you might help me to solve it.

So, I have the following schema in my database:

**Games**

id_game

**Players**

id_player

**Role_Players**

id_role
description

**Games_players**

role_id
game_id
player_id

Now, I have a many to many relationships with games and players and the following model

```
 class Games {

    public function players {

     return $this->belongsToMany(Players::class, Games_players,  id_game, id_player)     


   }
}
```

This will return all the players associated with games, but how can I return the role of the players in this game? I know that I have an object $games->players->pivot where I can add the column role_id, but how can I get for example the description using eloquent? I'm struggling to get this work.

I will appreciate any help.

Thanks.

D

Comment: This looks like a ternary relationship which eloquent does not support. You could probably refer to the [many to many](https://laravel.com/docs/5.5/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many) documentation subsection *Defining Custom Intermediate Table Models* and check whether creating a custom pivot can work for you

Answer (score 0):

You can create a model for your pivot table with its own relations and work off of that. So a model for Games_players will have a relationship to roles, players and games, and vice versa.

These relationships do not have to replace your current manyToMany relationships, they can both be there at the same time.

Answer (score 0):

I have an idea.

You can add relation to your Players model somethink like this

```
class Players {

    public function roles {

     return $this->belongsToMany(Roles::class, Games_players,  id_player, id_role )     

   }
}
```

Then you can use **Eager Loading**

`$games = Games::with('players.roles')->get()`